# How to set Drawer native base to right position - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using the `native base` library. I want to use the `Drawer` [component](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Drawer), but I want to set it to the right position.  How can I do this, as there is no property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `side` prop for it[[*](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1628)].

```
<Drawer
    side="right"
    ref={ref => {
        this.drawer = ref;
    }}
    content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} />}
    onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
/>
```